# RegEx to match a string in a HTML tag not containing specific class

Tags: php, regex

I want to use Regex to find all words matches in HTML code and then replace them with the links, but I need to exclude tags with specific class from search.
In this example I need to find all words as:

> "awesome"

and exclude from search all tags with class:

> goaway

And finally replace them with (only inside tags, not in titles or ALTs attributes) my link:

```
<a href="mysite.com">awesome</a>
```

Source HTML code:

```
<p> 
    this is awesome text about my cat 
    <img src="cat.jpg" title="my awesome cat"/>
</p>
<p class="goaway">
    I don't need this awesome match 
</p>
<div>
    and this is element of my awesome code
</div>
<span class="goaway">
    That isn't awesome word
</span>
```

I am doing replacements with `preg_replace_callback()` function, and this is what I want to see as result:

```
<p>
    this is <a href="mysite.com">awesome</a> text about my cat
    <img src="cat.jpg" title="my awesome cat"/>
</p>
<p class="goaway">
    I don't need this awesome match 
</p>
<div>
    and this is element of my <a href="mysite.com">awesome</a> code
</div>
<span class="goaway">
    That isn't awesome word
</span>
```

Right now everything what I achieved is a pattern to ignore attributes content

```
"|(?!<.*?)awesome(?![^<>]*?>)|"
```

So, I need your help with completing the RegEx pattern. Thanks!

P.S. English, do I speak it?.. Nope, and I'm so sorry for that, but I hope you can understand my thoughts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this RegEx:

```
(<(?!\s+class="goaway")[^>]*>[\w\n\s]*)(awesome)
```

And replace like this:

```
\1<a href="mysite.com">awesome</a>
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/dI9cD0/1)</kbd>

Comment: thank you, thats exactly what I needed!
You are awesome, btw ;D

Comment: @evilmolen No Problem! `;)`